# Replacing dots in plots with an uploaded image/icon?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

Is it possible in plots created with the `pgfplots` package to replace data point symbols (the dot) with a homemade image or icon? Such as the bullet points in the simple graph:

[image]

I would like to be able to illustrate data points with a homemade small image in .jpg or .png format.

The code is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
]
\addplot[only marks] coordinates {
    (1,5)
    (2,5)
    (3,5)
    (4,5)
    (5,5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `text mark`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    ymin=0,ymax=10,
]
\addplot[
   only marks,
   mark=text,
   text mark={\includegraphics[width=10pt]{example-image}}
   ] coordinates {
    (1,5)
    (2,5)
    (3,5)
    (4,5)
    (5,5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```