# Importing a .png image as a custom marker in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, includegraphics

I am trying to create scatter plot using an input .dat file with custom markers (which are saved as a .png file)

If I do not use the custom markers my plot is plotting correctly - it is overlaid on another image (`Overnight_loc.png`)

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits = false,
    hide axis,
    ]
        \addplot graphics [
        xmin=-80.5430, xmax=-80.5150,
        ymin=43.4580, ymax=43.4740,
        ]{Overnight_loc.png};
        \addplot+[
        only marks,
            mark=*,
        ]
        table {overnight.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

works perfectly and with standard `*` markers. If I change the code by adding:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{home}{%
        \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{home1.png};
        }
```

before the tikzpicture and set `mark=home` the code runs, my map appears and the custom markers appear, however they appear clustered at the bottom rather than at the positions they should appear given in `overnight.dat`.

How can I get tex to plot with my custom markers?

Comment: Hi, welcome. You can try using a `text mark`, like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384701/replacing-dots-in-plots-with-an-uploaded-image-icon/384705#384705

Answer (score 7):

Some random images to define a plotmark with image.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfdeclareimage[interpolate,height=4mm,width=8mm]{dmark}{dmark.jpg}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{dmark}{%
\pgftext[at=\pgfpointorigin]{\pgfuseimage{dmark}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits = false,hide axis]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=20,ymin=0,ymax=20]{Dark_Side_of_the_Moon};
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=dmark,domain=0:20,samples=10] {x};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]